# Weird behaviour of assignTo attribute in apex:param

Tags: apex, visualforce, apex-param

Today I was looking at a code that was exiting in the org from a long time and I was surprised to find that the the value assigned in the assignTo attribute in the `apex:param` tag doesn't exit in the controller. But below is the description for the `assignTo` attribute:

> A setter method that assigns the value of this param to a variable in
>   the associated Visualforce controller. If this attribute is used,
>   getter and setter methods, or a property with get and set values, must
>   be defined.

As you can see from the below code, I have not used any controller / extensions in the page, but still I can still use a variable `someVariable` in the assignTo attribute. The page compiles and renders fine. Looks like a bug to me. Any idea?

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton value="Do Something">
            <apex:param assignTo="{!someVariable}" value="clicked"/>
        </apex:commandButton>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you mention someVariable? i mean is it like {!Account.Name}

Comment: @snehakem: My intention was that the compiler should never have saved this page in the first place as the `sameVariable` doesn't exit. There's no standardController defined in the page, so it can't be `{Account.Name}`

Comment: Does it still compile if you have a `name` attribute? `apex:param` without a `name` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes it does compile after adding the `name` attribute